# Java Write Operation io_append io_write

Tags: java, randomaccessfile, hard-drive

I am triying to figure out how java writes bytes to disk.

If I look at the Randomaccesfile implementation, it has 
declared a native method and calls said native method to write to the disk when write(byte[]) is called.

source code for randomaccesfile:http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/io/RandomAccessFile.java#RandomAccessFile.writeBytes%28byte%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29

```
private native void writeBytes(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException;

public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException {
    writeBytes(b, 0, b.length);
}
```

I searched inside the OpenJDK for writeBytes and found it inside `io_util.c`
Here the functions `IO_Append(fd, buf+off, len);` and `IO_Write(fd, buf+off, len);`
are called.

these functions can be found for Windows and Solaris inside the JDK in io_util_md.h

```
/*
* Route the routines
*/
#define IO_Sync fsync
#define IO_Read handleRead
#define IO_Write handleWrite
#define IO_Append handleWrite
#define IO_Available handleAvailable
#define IO_SetLength handleSetLength
```

Why can't i find the same for Linux?And what do `io_append` and `io_write` actually do?I can't find how they are implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that Solaris and Linux share the native code base for everything below
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/

[io_util_md.h](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/solaris/native/java/io/io_util_md.h) defines (for Solaris and Linux)

```
#define IO_Append JVM_Write
#define IO_Write JVM_Write
```

Now `JVM_Write` is defined in the hotspot code base, in [jvm.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp):

```
JVM_LEAF(jint, JVM_Write(jint fd, char *buf, jint nbytes))
    JVMWrapper2("JVM_Write (0x%x)", fd);
    //%note jvm_r6
    return (jint)os::write(fd, buf, nbytes);
JVM_END
```

calling a OS dependent write function. The Linux implementation is in [os_linux.inline.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/hotspot/file/tip/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.inline.hpp#l187)

```
inline size_t os::write(int fd, const void *buf, unsigned int nBytes) {
    size_t res;
    RESTARTABLE((size_t) ::write(fd, buf, (size_t) nBytes), res);
    return res;
}
```